# how to get UIImageView coordinates?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiview

I have to calculate an angle beetween two UIImageView and i don't find how to get the UIImageViews coordinates(the four corners coordinates).
Is there a property for that?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to find any angle with trigonometric functions.

For example, this will find the angle between the centers of two UIImageViews that share a superview:

```
angle = tan((imageView1.center.y-imageView2.center.y),
            (imageView1.center.x-imageView2.center.x));
```

It is important that they are in the same superview, otherwise the coordinates will be different. To find angles you need to have an understanding of basic [trigonometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry).

Answer (score 0):

`self.frame` will give you a CGRect with the coordinates of the view.

Comment: Note that if the view is rotated (using the transform property) then the frame property is meaningless. From the UIView documentation:

Warning: If the transform property is not the identity transform, the value of this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

Comment: Thank you both. I used the transform property. So i can't use that way (self.frame?!). Precisely i just want to get the angle between the 2 UIImageView. Can you tell me a way to get that angle, please? (i can't try now, my MAC is at work :§)